# Chrome browser pages invisible

Tags: google-chrome, browser

newly my chrome browser running on windows 10 does not show anymore any tabs.
They are still there, i figured out but it seems the colors are messed up.
Foreground and background is white. Same applies for some add in, like Last Pass.

This happened suddenly on more than one machine. Both windows 10, ver 1703
but one happened after goolge chrome update.

How can i restore old colors or what is the reason for that.
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this problem by disabling hardware acceleration.